# C: Output with symbols in Caesar’s cipher encrypts, WHY? pset2 cs50

Tags: c, string, c-strings, cs50

This is Caesar’s cipher encrypts problem in pset2 of cs50x course in edx.org.

I already solved this problem with another algorithm but this was my first try and I'm still curious why appear all these symbols at the right side of the caesar text.

ie. I enter the text "`Testing`" and the output is "`Fqefuz�����w����l��B��`" but the answer is correct without the symbols.

Can anyone explain me that?

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    bool keyOk = false;
    int k = 0;   
    do
    {
        if(argc != 2) // Checking if the key was correctly entered.
        {
            printf("You should enter the key in one argument from"
                " the prompt(i.e. './caesar <key>').\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            k = atoi(argv[1]); // Converting string to int.
            keyOk = true; // Approving key.
        }
    }
    while(keyOk == false);

    string msg = GetString(); // Reading user input.
    char caesarMsg[strlen(msg)];

    for(int i=0, n = strlen(msg); i < n; i++)
    {

        if( (msg[i] >= 'a') && (msg[i] <= 'z') )
        // Processing lower case characters
        {
            caesarMsg[i] = ((((msg[i] - 97) + k) % 26) + 97);
        }
        else if( (msg[i] >= 'A') && (msg[i] <= 'Z') )
        // Processing upper case characters
        {
            caesarMsg[i] = ((((msg[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65);
        }
        else
        {
            caesarMsg[i] = msg[i];
        }

    }
    printf("%s", caesarMsg);
    printf("\n");        
}
```

Comment: Your newly encoded string buffer is 1 byte too small. You need to have room for the terminating zero as well. (Additionally, you don't even add that terminating zero.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does it mean to be "terminated by a zero"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667648/what-does-it-mean-to-be-terminated-by-a-zero)

Comment: `char caesarMsg[strlen(msg)];` --> `char caesarMsg[strlen(msg)+1];`

Comment: I already tried with this "char caesarMsg[strlen(msg)+1];" and don't work. I recently read about Terminating zero, I'll keep in mind.Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `caesarMsg[strlen(msg)]=0;printf("%s", caesarMsg);`

Comment: OT: if you are going to check against the literal characters 'a'..'z' and 'A'..'Z', better also use these in the next calculations, instead of the semi-magical values "97" and "65".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is C does **not** have a full, proper, or first-class "string" datatype. In [C strings](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx8.html) are in fact character arrays that are terminated with the `NUL` (`'\0'`) (*) character.

Look at

```
  string msg = GetString();  // Reading user input.
  char caesarMsg[strlen(msg)];
```

This is equivalent to

```
  char* msg = GetString();  /* User or library function defined elsewhere */

/* calculates the length of the string s, excluding  the terminating null
   byte ('\0') */
  size_t len = strlen(msg);  

  char caesarMsg[len];  /* Create an character (byte) array of size `len` */
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer, why this section fails to work correctly. The variable `len` that I've added, is the length of the sequence of non-NUL characters in the string `msg`. So when you create the character array `caesarMsg` of length `len`, there is no room for the NUL character to be stored.

The `for` loop correctly executes, but the `printf("%s", caesarMsg);` will continue to print characters until it finds a NUL or crashes.

BTW you can reduce the two `printf` statements at the end into a single `printf` statement easily.

```
printf("%s\n", caesarMsg);
```

Strings and character arrays are a frequent source of confusion to anyone new to C, and some not-so-new to C. Some additional references:

- I *really* recommend bookmarking is the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).
- I also **strongly** that you have either get your own copy or ensure you have [access](https://www.worldcat.org/title/c-programming-language/oclc/17650642&referer=brief_results) to Kernighan and Ritchie's [The C Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/), Second Edition (1988).

---

Rant: And whoever created the `string` typedef is evil / making a grave error, by misleading students that into thinking C's strings are are a "real" (or first-class) data type.

---

(*) [NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) is different from [NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#Null_pointer), because `NULL` (the null-pointer) is cast as a pointer as so it the same size as other pointers, where as `NUL` is a null-character (and either the size of a `char` or `int`).

Comment: Michael Taylor, thanks for the excellent info.

In the for loop I change this:
n = strlen(msg)
for this
n = strlen(msg) + 1

and works like a charm.

Thanks you, I really appreciate the info.